# Opportunity Stage Picklist value (with probability field - percentage)

Tags: picklist

In Opportunity, I wish to create a custom field like 'StageName' having a similiar function and layout as in the screenshot:

[image]

1. How can create such field?
2. If this is not possible I've a question why such different layout/function for this field alone (StageName) ?

Comment: You can do it with dependant pick lists. The StageName was built that way to make it easy on the End Users to configure a key part of the opportunity. Unfortunately there is no way to create that type of field the same way as the stage does.

Comment: Thkx Eric, i did via dependent picklist but wanted to see if anything can be done like the one in the post....i think it is clarified now.